# string subscript out of range

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Задача: посчитать количество слов в строке начинающихся с букв латиницы. на сторонних онлайн-компиляторах данная программа работает безошибочно , но в Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 уже в консоли выдает ошибку *string subscript out of range*. Надеюсь кто-то сможет мне помочь

```
        #include <iostream>
        #include <string>
        
        using namespace std;
        int number(string s) {
            int counter = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i<s.size(); i++) {
                if (s[i] >= 65 && s[i] <= 90 || s[i] >= 97 && s[i] <= 122) {
                    if (!isalpha(s[i - 1])) {
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
            }
            return counter;
        }
        
        
        
        int main()
        {
            int amount;
            string s = "Hello Wordl";
            amount = number(s);
            cout << amount;
        }
```

Comment: `string subscript out of range` И что же здесь неизвестного? `s[i - 1]` Уберите `- 1` и все заработает.

Answer (score 1):

Когда проверка выполняется для первого символа (`i = 0`), этот код обращается к `s[-1]`:

```
if (!isalpha(s[i - 1])) {
```

Поэтому Visual Studio и выдает ошибку. Добавьте проверку, что `i` не равно нулю:

```
  if (!i || !isalpha(s[i - 1])) {
```

Такая проверка будет считать первый символ началом слова и не проверять для него предыдущий символ. Для остальных будет проверять предыдущий символ.